# Tipo de dato Interval en Oracle con C#

Tags: c#, .net, base-de-datos, oracle

Espero me puedan ayudar con mi problema que es el siguiente:

Tengo una aplicación hecha en `C#` que se conecta a una base de datos de `Oracle`, y a su vez en esta tengo una tabla con un campo `INTERVAL DAY(2) TO SECOND(6)" (TIEMPOEJECUCION)`  cuando me traigo todos los campos de la tabla lee todos correctamente **excepto este campo Interval** ya intenté de todo hasta hacer un cast y nada me funciona, espero me puedan ayudar.

PD: Lo mas curioso es que en el `SQL Developer` si veo la información del Tipo `Interval`

Saludos!

```
public static Documento SelectByNUNICODOCT(long NUNICODOCT)
{
    var resultado = (Documento)null;

   using (var conexion = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CadenaConexion"].ConnectionString))
    using (var comando = conexion.CreateCommand())
    {
        comando.CommandText = "SELECT NUNICODOCT , TIPODOCUMENTO , IDEQUIPO , NOHOJAS , NOHOJASPROC , TIEMPOEJECUCION, FECHADESCARGA , FECHAPROCESO , FECHAREGRESO , PESO  FROM APP_OCR.DOCUMENTO WHERE NUNICODOCT=:NUNICODOCT";
        comando.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("NUNICODOCT", NUNICODOCT));

        using (var lector = comando.ExecuteReader())
           if (lector.Read())
              resultado = Mapping(lector);

           if (conexion.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                    conexion.Close();
     }

     return resultado;
}

private static Documento Mapping(OracleDataReader lector)
{
    var resultado = new Documento();

    resultado.NUNICODOCT = lector.GetInt64(0);
    resultado.TipoDocumento = lector.GetInt16(1);
    if (!lector.IsDBNull(2))
       resultado.IdEquipo = lector.GetInt64(2);
    if (!lector.IsDBNull(3))
       resultado.NoHojas = lector.GetInt32(3);
    if (!lector.IsDBNull(4))
       resultado.NoHojasProc = lector.GetInt32(4);
    if (!lector.IsDBNull(5)) // Esta línea siempre lleva el valor Nulo
       resultado.TiempoEjecucion = lector.GetTimeSpan(5);
    if (!lector.IsDBNull(6))
       resultado.FechaDescarga = lector.GetDateTime(6);
    if (!lector.IsDBNull(7))
       resultado.FechaProceso = lector.GetDateTime(7);
    if (!lector.IsDBNull(8))
       resultado.FechaRegreso = lector.GetDateTime(8);
    if (!lector.IsDBNull(9))
       resultado.Peso = lector.GetInt64(9);

    return resultado;
}
```

Comment: hola! bienvenido a SOes, te sugiero que cambies esa postada que pones por tu código. También visita estos enlaces: http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask saludos :D

Comment: Buenas, Seimpre viene un `DBNull` ?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar a usar el método [GetOracleIntervalDS(int colIndex)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleDataReaderClass.htm#i1005872) de la siguiente forma para recuperar una estructura de tipo OracleIntervalDS

```
var interval = lector.GetOracleIntervalDS(5);
```